# Can I recover data from a hard drive after booting another OS from a USB drive?

Tags: usb-flash-drive, ubuntu-16.04

My hard drive looks like it has broken. (My laptop might have been dropped.) Everything looks like it still works until I reboot Ubuntu. There is no bootable device found.

I'm going to go to a store to fix this, but I still want to know if I can boot another system with a USB drive and then recover my data from the non-bootable HDD without opening the case?

Answer (score 0):

It is very likely they are recoverable, but it has to be Linux based to read ext[?] file systems. Depending on the extent of damage it may still be accesible.

I recommend the [Ultimate Boot CD or UBCD](http://www.ultimatebootcd.com/). It has many tools and a Linux based OS to boot (pun). The UBCD is an advanced toolset with many tools to help you possibly possibly fix your hard drive and if possible restore many of your files. It is essential that you do not improperly use the tools else you definitely will loose you data and files; use at your own risk and discretion. I recommend using **Parted Magic** OS that comes with it. I also recommend if the files seem lost to try and use **testdisk** which is installed with the bootable OS. All these tools require some basic knowledge of data storage and file systems. I am not responsible for what you do even if I told you to do it. Use at your own risk.

Comment: Moderators, did I advocate this product in an inappropiate way on superuser?

Comment: ok thank you,i will open the case first then remove and reinstall the hard drive,if there's any problem.i will have to ask fixers to fix it to recovery data first.

Comment: "did I advocate this product in an inappropriate way on superuser?" – The answer may be here: *[How do I recommend software in my answers?](https://meta.superuser.com/q/5329/432690)* If you want to be sure your question gets to moderators then ask it in [this chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/114/ask-a-super-user-moderator).